# GDAL installation problem: Linux server without sudo privileges

Tags: gdal, proj, rgdal

I'm having problems installing GDAL on my account on a remote Linux server where I can't use sudo. Ultimately I want to use RStudio and Rgdal, but it looks like I need to install GDAL and PROJ4 first.

I'm not a Linux expert!

Here's what I did: 
created a directory where I have write privileges
got gdal from ​http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.1.2/gdal212.zip with wget
ran ./configure --prefix=/path/to/my/directory
ran make

This is were I had problems.

```
~/gdal-2.1.2/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to 'SQLFetchScroll'
~/gdal-2.1.2/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to 'SQLDrivers'
...
```

And about 50 further undefined references, mainly to SQL functions but also to a few XML and other functions.

Comment: This doesn't answer your questions, but Linux virtual servers w root access are fairly inexpensive. Do you need to use this specific server?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that. I have a lot of space on this particular server, so it would be easier if I could keep my data and do GIS stuff there.

Comment: Try `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH= /path/to/libs` or the equivalent, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the Anaconda package manager. You can use a user only, not root installation to your home directory (or wherever you have write access).

1. Install [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html#linux-miniconda-install)
2. Create a conda environment with gdal
3. Activate it

```bash
#python 3
conda create -n py3 python>=3 gdal>=2.1
#python 2
conda create -n py2 python=2.7 gdal>=2.1
```

```bash
source activate py3 #or py2
gdalinfo --version
```